# file transfer through bluetooth

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk

is it possible to transfer files from one android phone to any other device through bluetooth?
if possible the send give me a link the sample code...

```
switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                    mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName);
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                               + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
```

Comment: Please first go through http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask to know how to ask a question with proper formatting. Is your code readable to you at least?

Comment: @rajkiran give me some suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of transferring the files you can make an explicit call to `ACTION_SEND` using intents as shown below.

You can send a file to a paired device through obex in a couple of ways:

With the `ACTION_SEND` intent, that will popup a menu with the application that can handle the file type you want to send, from which the user will need to select bluetooth, and then the device.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); i.setType("image/jpeg");    
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/sdcard/file.jpg")); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Image"));
```

For more visit

[Bluetooth Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)